# can't get rid of this errors

Tags: php, html

so i've been working on some project that needs to display a database table in a page, but since it has a lot of data i use pagination to make it look more simple, the code was run perfectly and the table was shown in the right way.

but i've got this error message :

> Notice: Undefined variable: _PHP_SELF in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test2\test4.php on line 74

that bugging me cause i can't find what it is and how to get rid of it from my page, i need help cause this project deadline gonna be over soon

so here's the code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Paging Using PHP</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$rec_limit = 10;

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('test1');
/* Get total number of records */
$sql = "SELECT count(msisdn) FROM bbs_1 ";
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
$row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_NUM );
$rec_count = $row[0];

if( isset($_GET{'page'} ) )
{
   $page = $_GET{'page'} + 1;
   $offset = $rec_limit * $page ;
}
else
{
   $page = 0;
   $offset = 0;
}
$left_rec = $rec_count - ($page * $rec_limit);

$sql = "SELECT bill_cycle, total_bill_amount, total_outstanding_amount ".
       "FROM bbs_1 ".
       "LIMIT $offset, $rec_limit";

$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
    echo"<table>".
            "<tr>".
                "<td>CYCLE</td>".
                "<td>TOTBILL</td>".
                "<td>OUTSTANDING</td>".
            "</tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo 
            "<tr>".
                "<td>{$row['bill_cycle']} </td>".
                "<td>{$row['total_bill_amount']}</td>".
                "<td>{$row['total_outstanding_amount']}</td>".
             "</tr>";

} 
echo "</table>";
if( $page > 0 )
{
   $last = $page - 2;
   echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$last\">Last 10 Records</a> |";
   echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$page\">Next 10 Records</a>";
}
else if( $page == 0 )
{
   echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$page\">Next 10 Records</a>";
}
else if( $left_rec < $rec_limit )
{
   $last = $page - 2;
   echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$last\">Last 10 Records</a>";
}
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

hope you can find the problem,

Comment: Don't make up `$_PHP_SELF` ; it should be `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];`; and stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use MySQLi / PDO instead

Comment: the problem is quite obvious, it even shows you the line (74).`$_PHP_SELF` doesn't exist it's supposed to `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`

Answer (score 0):

The browser will figure out what to do given only the question mark and query string; there's no need to tell it to apply them to the current URL.